# Inequality with differential opertaors

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I want to prove the following inequality
$$
\left\Vert \left( I-\partial _{x}^{2}\right) ^{-1}\partial
_{x}^{4}u\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)}\leq C\left\Vert \partial
_{x}^{2}u\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)}
$$
for all $v \in (H_0^2 \cap {H^4})(0,1)$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$

let $v\in D(0,1)$ ($D(0,1)$ is the space of $C^{\infty }$ function with
compact support in $(0,1))$

It is well known that $D(0,1)$ is dense in $L^{2}(0,1).$ we can extend
easelly  $v\in D(0,1)$  to $\widetilde{v}\in D(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)$with support in $(0,1).$

the symbole of the operator $\left( I-\partial _{x}^{2}\right) ^{-1}\partial
_{x}^{4}$ in Fourier space is $\frac{\xi ^{4}}{\xi ^{2}+1}$ so we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\Vert \frac{\xi ^{4}}{\xi ^{2}+1}\widehat{\widetilde{v}}(\xi
)\right\Vert _{L^{2}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)} &=&\int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
}\left( \frac{\xi ^{4}}{\xi ^{2}+1}\right) ^{2}\widehat{\widetilde{v}}%
^{2}(\xi )d\xi \leq \int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
}\left( \xi ^{2}\right) ^{2}\widehat{\widetilde{v}}^{2}(\xi )d\xi  \\
&\leq &\int_{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
}\left( \xi ^{2}+1\right) ^{2}\widehat{\widetilde{v}}^{2}(\xi )d\xi
=\left\Vert \widetilde{v}\right\Vert _{H^{2}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)}
\end{eqnarray*}

by using the Plancherel theorem we get
$$
\left\Vert \left( I-\partial _{x}^{2}\right) ^{-1}\partial _{x}^{4}%
\widetilde{v}\right\Vert _{L^{2}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)}\leq \left\Vert \widetilde{v}\right\Vert _{H^{2}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)}
$$

but we have $supp(\widetilde{v})\subset (0,1)$ so we have

$$
\left\Vert \left( I-\partial _{x}^{2}\right) ^{-1}\partial
_{x}^{4}v\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)
)}\leq \left\Vert v\right\Vert _{H_{0}^{2}(0,1)
%EndExpansion
)}
$$

for all $v$ in $D(0,1).$

Now we use the density argument to prove the desired result.

My question is: is my attempt is write ? Is there any problems in it ?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry if this is silly, but is the symbol in Fourier space correct?  Should it not be $\frac{\xi^4}{1-\xi^2}$?  I don't think this impacts your estimate though.

Comment: no, the symbol is correct ( integrating twice in the fourier transform)...if the symbole is $\xi^4/(\xi^2-1)$ this will change everything. now, what do you think about my proof?

Comment: There is no need to estimate $(\xi^2)^2$ by $(\xi^2+1)^2$. The integral of $(\xi^2)^2 \widehat{\overline{v}}^2$ already gives $\|\partial_x^2 v\|_{L^2}^2$. Actually, there should be an absolute value of the square of the Fourier transform.

Comment: so, Is my proof correcte ? is there any problem?